# Rename attribute on NATURAL JOIN

Tags: mysql

Is it possible, in MySQL, to rename the attributes of a table in a NATURAL JOIN like this:

```
select * FROM AAA NATURAL JOIN BBB AS NEW_NAME(ATTR_ONE, ATTR_TWO);
```

According to Fundamentals of Database Systems - Ramez Elmasri a DBMS should allow it, but I found no way to do it on MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working MySQL for over a decade and I've never seen it; and if it supported such a feature, I am fairly certain it would be mentioned in the official docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

In fact, I am not sure I ever recall reading about such a feature even in relational algebra, though my formal training did end over a decade ago.

How would such an operation even work; is it supposed to substitute AAA.ATTR_ONE for a missing AAA.ATTR_TWO in the JOIN? or is it supposed to alias the result field? or something else?

---

Fairly certain the only alternative is something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM AAA 
NATURAL JOIN (
   SELECT field0 AS ATTR_ONE, field1 AS ATTR_TWO FROM BBB
) AS NEW_NAME
```

where field0 and field1 should be replaced with actual field names from BBB.

...actually, I am starting to find the book's claim rather dubious; it is assuming a column order that (while may exist in practice) cannot be assumed any stronger than row order.

Comment: If BBB had attributes named (one, two), the result of NEW_NAME(ATTR_ONE, ATTR_TWO) should create a "new" table with the given table and attribute names.

Comment: Ah, so aliasing the table and columns together? Does that have anything specific to do with NATURAL JOIN, or was that just your intended use? Either way, after just searching on aliasing in MySQL in general, it looks like it does not provide such syntax.

Comment: It should be helpful in case the tables have no attribute names in common. If you have the book you can find information on pag. 123

Comment: Most people I know, myself included, tend to stay away from `NATURAL JOIN` altogether; it's nice syntactic sugar but it is too susceptible to unintended alteration (_someone adds/removes/renames a field to one table or the other, that they previously didn't have or whose existence was assumed when the query was first created; and now you have a query that is still valid but can return drastically different results; if all common fields are removed, you get the cartesian product, if a new common field is added that defaults to a value not in the other table, you get no results..._)

Comment: @welcome Also, I don't think I have that book, but I recall the textbook we used in the course I took had a lot of theoretical features I don't think I've seen implemented in any real world db.